# Enable button clicking on caption of photo browser (Framework 7)

Tags: html-framework-7

**What I did**: currently the photo browser have a caption to show, and its perfect.
I create some link/button inside the caption.
example:

```
myPhotoBrowserStandalone = myApp.photoBrowser({
photos : [
{
url: photoURL,
caption: description+"<a href='#' class='close-popup button button-fill'>Close Popup</a>"
},],type: 'popup'
});
```

**Expected Behavior**: I expect the link/button in the caption could be clicked, so that it could link to other pages or close the photo browser.

**Actual Behavior**: It dont click on it, the clicking is just passing through the link button.

I check through the framework7.js file and dont recognize any code that set the caption to unselectable. Any help would be appreciated.